# Java Stack peek method displays 0 instead of correct number

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, peek

I can't seem to understand what the logic error is in this class assignment. I am to make a stack using a linked list. Outer and Inner class should be implemented in UserStack. UserStack implements the MyStack provided by the teacher. StackApp houses the main.

It compiles and runs. It properly asks for an integer to be entered. Will remove if there is something to remove and will try to peek if there is something to show. But it always says it removed or is displaying the number 0.

Do I need to try to do a toString override? I asked my professor and he told me to just go to google like other students.

MyStack.java

```
public interface MyStack
{
    public void push (int item);

    public int pop ();

    public int peek ();

    public boolean isEmpty ();

}
```

UserStack.java

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class UserStack implements MyStack
{
    private class Node
    {
        public int value;
        public Node link;

        public Node(int data)
        {
            data = value;
        }
    }

    private Node head = null;

    public void push (int item)
    {
        Node newHead = new Node(item);
        newHead.link = head;
        head = newHead;
    }

    public int pop ()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        int tmp = head.value;
        head = head.link;

        return tmp;
    }

    public int peek ()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        int tmp = head.value;

        return tmp;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty ()
    {
        return head == null;
    }
}
```

StackApp.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class StackApp
{
    UserStack stack = new UserStack();
    public void displayMenu()
    {
        System.out.println ("1) Add an integer to the list\n" +
                            "2) Remove last integer entered\n" +
                            "3) Look at last integer entered\n" +
                            "0) Exit the program");
        System.out.print ("Selection: ");
    }

    public StackApp()
    {
        int option;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
        displayMenu();
        option = input.nextInt();

        switch (option)
        {
            case 1:
              int number;
              System.out.println("Enter integer to add: ");
              number = input.nextInt();
              stack.push(number);
              break;
            case 2:
              int number2 = stack.pop();
              System.out.println("Interger removed: " + number2);
              break;
            case 3:
              int number3 = stack.peek();
              System.out.println("Next Interger: " + number3);
              break;
            case 0:
              System.out.println("Goodbye");
              break;
            default:
              System.err.println("Unrecongized choice");
              break;
        }
        }while(option != 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new StackApp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo in your `Node` constructor: `data = value;` should be `value = data;`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been staring at this since Monday and never noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting the `value` of the new item.

Comment: It seems fairly obvious to me that the problem isn't in `push`, but in the `Node` constructor...

Comment: What is obvious to an expert may not be to a beginner.

Comment: @SomeStudent Jon is referring to a previous state of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Mate, try switching around your values assignment in your Node constructor:

Original:

```
public Node(int data)
        {
            data = value;
        }
```

New:

```
public Node(int data)
        {
            this.value = data;
        }
```

Also, the usage of the keyword "this" is important as your are letting the program know that we want to set this class level variable "value" to that of data. As such, you must use the keyword "this". I am quite certain that your assignment was a bit off as you set your "data" equal to that of "value", and, because value never had an initial value explicitly set, it defaults to 0.

Comment: Using `this` is *not* essential here, although I agree it is good practice in constructors, as would have been using the same name for the parameter.